# How can I shorten this xpath expression?

Tags: xpath, set, expression

I have defined a variable called tags which selects a node set of elements whose names are one of several values:

```
<xsl:variable name="tags" select="//xs:element[@name='Subscription' or @name='Account' or @name='Product'  or @name='ProductRatePlan' or @name='ProductRatePlanCharge' or @name='Usage']"/>
```

I would like to define a variable as such:

```
<xsl:variable name="tagNames" select="'Subscription','Account','Product','ProductRatePlan','ProductRatePlanCharge','Usage'/>
```

How could I rewrite the first expression to select all the nodes whose names are in the set $tagNames? In essence, I'm looking for an operation that is analagous to a SQL set membership:

```
SELECT * FROM tags WHERE name in ('Subscription', 'Account', 'Product'....)
```

Comment: Which version of XSLT do you use?

Answer (score 2):

In XPath 2.0 you can write:

```
<xsl:variable name="tags" select="//xs:element[@name=('Subscription','Account','Product','ProductRatePlan','ProductRatePlanCharge','Usage')]"/>
```

Comment: In XPath 1.0, you could do something like `<xsl:variable name="tags" select="//xs:element[contains(' Subscription Account Product ProductRatePlan ProductRatePlanCharge Usage ', concat(' ', @name, ' ' ' ')]"/>`.

Answer (score 1):

**One way to do this**:

```
//xs:element
  [contains('|Subscription|Account|Product|ProductRatePlan|ProductRatePlanCharge|Usage|',
            concat('|', @name, '|'))]
```

**So, you can have a variable or parameter**:

```
<xsl:variable name="vTags"
 select="'|Subscription|Account|Product|ProductRatePlan|ProductRatePlanCharge|Usage|'"/>
```

**and your main XPath expression becomes**:

```
//xs:element[contains($vTags, concat('|', @name, '|'))]
```